# Latency picking up click event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am having a little problem with latency when I check a checkbox on and try to drag and drop. When I select one checkbox and try to move it over it won't move. If I have click that checkbox and click on a different row then try to move it will work. It works the same no matter how many I check it won't get the newest row without clicking somewhere else first. Do I need to add another event to handle or pick up that the box now has been checked?

```
Private Sub datagridview_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.MouseDown
     mouseDownPosition = e.Location
End Sub

Private Sub datagridview_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles datagridview.MouseMove
If CheckMouseMovement(sender, datagridview, e) Then
    listofBuilds = New List(Of Build)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dataGridView.Rows
        If Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells.Item(0).Value) Then
            Dim t As Build = DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, Build)
            listofBuilds.Add(t)
        End If
    Next
    If listofBuilds.Count > 0 Then
        dataGridView.EndEdit()
        dataGridView.DoDragDrop(sender, dropEffect)
    End If
End If
End Sub

 Private Sub TabControl_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TabControl.DragEnter
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
 End Sub

Private Sub TabControl_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TabControl.DragDrop
    Dim DropPage As TabPage = GetTabPageByTab(TabControl.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y)))
    If DropPage IsNot TabControl.SelectedTab Then
        If DropPage Is Page1 Then
        If DropPage Is Page2 Then
        If DropPage Is Page3 Then
          //etc
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetTabPageByTab(ByVal point As Point) As TabPage
    For i As Integer = 0 To TabControl.TabPages.Count - 1
        If TabControl.GetTabRect(i).Contains(point) Then
             Return TabControl.TabPages.Item(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Try adding a call to [`datagridview.EndEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the beginning of the `datagridview_MouseMove` method.

Comment: Not sure about what the latency is referring to, but try setting your grid's EditMode property to EditOnEnter.

Comment: @Mark thank you that worked. Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a call to [`datagridview.EndEdit()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at the beginning of the `datagridview_MouseMove` method will commit the current edit operation and update the source data so that you can see the updated value in your code.